# Changing action bar menu color

Tags: java, android

```
ActionBar bar = getActionBar();
bar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable("COLOR"));
```

How to change the action-bar menu color.

```
<item android:id="@+id/about" android:title="@string/about"
    android:showAsAction="never" />

<item android:id="@+id/help" android:title="@string/help"
    android:showAsAction="never" />

<item android:id="@+id/signout" android:title="@string/signout"
    android:showAsAction="never" />
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to keep consistency in your theme, you might want to use this to create a new ActionBar style :

http://jgilfelt.github.com/android-actionbarstylegenerator/